# Understanding differential forms geometrically

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n \in V$ be a basis and $v_1,\cdots, v_k \in V$ be linearly independent vectors. Furthermore let $V^*$ be the dual space of $V$ with $\{e^i\}_{i=1}^n$ as the dual basis. Then if I take a vector $v \in V$ then its components wrt $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ can be found by acting the dual basis $\{e^i\}_{i=1}^n$ on it, that is
$$
v^i = e^i(v) 
$$
Now if I take the vector constructed by the wedge product
$$
w = v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k
$$
which lives in a $\Lambda^k V$ and which represents the oriented $k$-dimensional volume in $V$ spanned by $v_1,\cdots, v_k \in V$. Then...

**Question:** does it make sense to say that the components of $w$ in $\Lambda^k V$ wrt $\{e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_k}\}_{1 \le i_1<\cdots<i_k\le n}$ can be found by acting $\{e^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e^{i_k}\}_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_k\le n}$, which is the (dual) basis of the dual space $(\Lambda^k V)^* = \Lambda^k V^*$, on $w$ ? that is
\begin{align}
w^{i_1\cdots i_k} &= (e^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e^{i_k})(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k) \\
&= (e^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e^{i_k})(v_1,\cdots,v_k) \\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\ e^{i_1}(v_{\sigma(1)})\cdots e^{i_k}(v_{\sigma(k)})\\
&= \det\left( e^{i}(v_j) \right), \qquad\qquad i \in \{i_1,\dots,i_k\}, j \in \{1,\dots,k \}.
\end{align}

---

The last expression of the component is the oriented volume of the "shadow" of the $k$-dimensional volume in $V$ on the subspace spanned by $e_{i_1},\dots, e_{i_k} \in V$.

Comment: As far as I understand it's all correct and it makes sense. .

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if I take
$$
w = v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k + \cdots + w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_k
$$
what are the modifications, with explanation please ?

Comment: $v_1\wedge \ldots \wedge v_k \longmapsto (e^{i_1}\wedge \ldots\wedge e^{i_k})(v_1\wedge \ldots \wedge v_k)$ is linear, so you simply take the linear combination of the corresponding alterned sums.