# Tensor notation what is $\Lambda^k(V^*)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

I am trying to understand tensors and there is a bit of notation that I am a bit confused about:

$\Lambda^{n}(V^*)$.
I know the formal definition is "subspace of alternating covariant k-tensors", but that is not giving me much intuition on the matter.

Is there an intuition or less formal definition I can use to build a high level understanding of the concept?

Comment: Does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914739/understanding-differential-forms-geometrically ?

Comment: not much to be honest: p

Comment: Are you comfortable with determinants? They are the prototype of these objects. If so, check out my YouTube lectures on differential forms, linked in my profile for a more concrete treatment of these objects.

Comment: Is there one you would recommend for this specific topic? Your YT library is quite complete.

Comment: Start around lecture 24 (revised) or 25 in 3510. Titles are good clues.